# Table style arrangement

Tags: tables

I would love to make all tables in the same style. I use the same parameters for all but then some tables look different. How can solve this issue? Thank you.

I use:

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Compliance results for single lattice morphology of the MBB beam model}
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c} 
    \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Relative Density} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Compliance ($mmN^{-1}$)} \\
     & D-type & G-type & I-WP-type & P-type \\ 
     \hline 
    0.10 & 1157.2 & 1147.4 & 1128.0 & 1074.8 \\  
    0.15 & 874.0 & 893.7 & 887.7 & 881.2 \\  
    0.20 & 718.4 & 744.2 & 734.1 & 754.7 \\  
    0.25 & 613.3 & 642.7 & 623.8 & 657.5 \\  
    0.30 & 535.2 & 566.3 & 536.5 & 578.3 \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

the table become in the form of
[image]

However I would like it to be similar to

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Material properties of CoCr}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \hline
    Material & Elastic Modulus, $E_s$ & Poisson's ratio, $v$ & Density, ${\rho }_s$ \\ \hline 
    CoCr & 236 GPa & 0.33 & 8.3\times {10}^{-9}\ $g/cc$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

the table seems to like this
[image]

I want the font of the first table to be like in the second table (Material Properties of CoCr).

Comment: Please complete the code.

Comment: You wrote, "...but then some tables look different ...". That would be because of `\resizebox`: some tables' font sizes will be minuscule, other tables' font sizes will be gigantic. Whatever else you, *don't ever apply `\resizebox` to tables*.

Comment: Apart from the font size difference Mico explains, what is it about the first table you want to be more like the second? The font is the same apart from the scaling from the resizebox, which yes, you should remove.

Comment: Thank you so much Mico and frabjous, I have just realized my mistake. I removed the \resizebox and the problem solved. Have a nice day :)